# symbolic solution pde

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

`eqns = {w D[c[x, t], t] + u D[c[x, t], x] - 
     v D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] == -k c[x, t] s[x, t], 
   D[s[x, t], t] == -p k c[x, t] s[x, t]};
sol = DSolve[eqns, {c, s}, {x, t}]`

the boundaries conditions are

`c(0, t) = cd(t), for  t in [0,T],
c(L, t) = 0, for t in [0,T],
c(x,0) = 0, for x in [0,L],
s(x,0) = s0, for x in [0,L].`
c and s are two functions defined in [0, T]x[0, L]

w,u,v,k, and p are constants

can anyone plz help me find a symbolic solution to my system

Comment: I don't  think that if even put $s0=0$ so $s(x,t)\equiv0$ the solution $c(x,t,)$ will have a closed form.

Comment: Even a numerical solution will get a problem. All parameters and boundary conditions must be specified: `L,T, cd[t], k, p, u, v`.

Comment: if I specify the parameters I am able to find numerical solutions
what I want is a symbolic one if possible